# Using an initialized object from one .cpp in another .cpp file without classess

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I'm trying to split some functionality between multiple .cpp files and I've got an issue. Let's say, I have:

`Extra.h`

```
#include "CustomClass.h"    
namespace extraSpace
{
    extern int justInteger;
    extern CustomClass *complexObject;
}
```

`Extra.cpp`

```
include "Extra.h"    
int extraSpace::justInteger = 1;
CustomClass *extraSpace::complexObject = new CustomClass;
complexObject->SomeProperty = 1; // Can't do this
```

`Main.cpp`

```
include "Extra.h"
int main()
{
   std::cout << extraSpace::justInteger << "\n";
   std::cout << extraSpace::complexObject->SomeProperty << "\n";
}
```

This code works well for `justInteger` variable. However, I cannot manipulate `complexObject` properties in `Extra.cpp`. Is there any simple workaround here?

I thought about creating some `InitObject()` function, but this would mean that I would have to change the object from `Main.cpp`, which I would rather not do.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a constructor. And you can't write executable statements like "complexObject.SomeProperty = 1;" outside of a function in any file.

Comment: The simple workaround is to write a constructor (or even just a function) that returns the custom object you require.

Comment: @273K I've made some changes in syntax, there were mistakes here. The option with the lambda function looks optimistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CustomClass *extraSpace::complexObject = new CustomClass;
complexObject->SomeProperty = 1; // Can't do this
```

You can use a lamda.

```
CustomClass *extraSpace::complexObject = [] {
  auto* complexObject = new CustomClass;
  complexObject->SomeProperty = 1;
  return complexObject;
}();
```

Comment: It worked. But may I ask why, in the structure of a lambda expression, the function body comes before the parameter list? Actually, I guess that parameter list is omitted, and it is something else.

Comment: The parameter list is optional and comes after `[]` before the body. What you see, `()` is a lambda call right after lambda is defined. `[](){}();` and `[]{}();` are the identical.

Comment: `[]{}` or `[](){}` is the lambda and the last `()` is the invokation of the lambda. You could write this as: `auto CustomFactory = [] { auto* complexObject = new CustomClass; complexObject->SomeProperty = 1; return complexObject; }; CustomClass *extraSpace::complexObject = CustomFactory();`